# REST API : fetch the listitem details using it's url

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, rest, jquery

I need to fetch the listitem details using it's url with REST API. The list item url is like :

```
http://<webappname>/Sites/<sitecollection name>/en-US/Pages/TVM3.aspx
```

I want to fetch the details of `TVM3.aspx` using this url, because I don't have any other information to fetch details.

Comment: This seems to be the URL of the page not the list. Kindly clear the requirement.

Comment: Mohor, as the other have stated, the URL you provided is not a list item URL, but a page URL. I can presume that your page may contains a list view webpart, but we actually need the URL of the list or list item to be able to give you a RESTful endpoint. A list item URL usually looks like this: `http://<webappname>/Sites/<sitecollection name>/Lists/<list name>/DispForm.aspx?ID=<list item id>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the ListItem details using REST API, we have to call the below endpoint,

```
https://webappname/sites/sitecollection_ name/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/Sites/sitecollection_name>/en-US/Pages/TVM3.aspx')/ListItemAllFields
```

**GetFileByServerRelativeUrl**( <server relative url of a file>)

**ListItemAllFields** property returns all field values of a file.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve page properties from a Pages library using REST just like any other list/library. For the above URL you could get that item using the following REST URL:

```
http://<webappname>/Sites/<sitecollection name>/en-US/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Pages')/items?$filter=FileRef eq '/sites/<sitecollection name/en-US/Pages/TVM3.aspx'
```

It would be better to reference by a different property such as ID or Title in the `$filter`, but the above should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
http://<webappname>/Sites/<sitecollection name>/en-US/Pages/TVM3.aspx
```

Above URL is not any end-point of REST API. End point of a list can be found in the following link.

[CRUD Operation to List Using SharePoint 2013 Rest API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API)

You can get the content of `TVM3.aspx` using `$.get` and from it you can find your list details

```
$.get(url,function(data){

});
```

See more about [jQuery.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)